# Method signature that takes any parameter as input

Tags: java, generics

How can I declare a method signature that takes `Long`, `Integer` as input?

I tried following but it gives a compilation error:

```
List<Myobject> fun ( ? extends Number) value){
 //impl       

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public <N extends Number>List<T>  xx(N a) {...}
```

Comment: if the return type is fixed, why not simply declare the argument as Number?

Answer (score 1):

This method takes any Number as input:
`private <N extends Number> void foo(N param) {}`

This one also returns List of the same type

`private <N extends Number> List<N> foo(N param) {}`

Comment: i want a method signature that takes any ip integer,long and returns object of predefined type

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply declare your argument as Number?

```
List<Myobject> fun (Number value){
 //impl       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<N extends Number> List<MyObject> fun(N value) { ... }
```

But in this use-case, I don't really see the benefit of using generics. I mean, why doesn't your method simply take a `Number` as argument ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
private <T extends Number> List<Myobject> fun(T value) {
    // do anything with the value
    return aMyobjectList;
}
```